# Can't get my Scanner to work with ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner

Hi sorry in advance about my bad code haha. I'm trying to get my code to read out what I type in the keyboard (only one phrase) forwards and then backwards however I keep getting errors with every different method I try.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;  
import java.util.Scanner;  
class hw  
{  
  public static void main(String[] args)
 {  
  Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);  
  ArrayList<String> sal = new ArrayList<String>();  
  sal.add(kb.next());
  sal.add(kb.next());
  sal.add(kb.next());
  display(sal);  
  displayb(sal);  


}
  public static void display(ArrayList<String> sal)
{
   for (int i=0; i<sal.size(); i++)
        System.out.print(sal.get(i)+ " ");
   System.out.println();
}
 public static void displayb(ArrayList<String> sal)
{

   for (int z = sal.size(); z >= 1; z--)
        System.out.print(sal.get(z-1) + " ");
   System.out.println();
}
}
```

I know this has something to do with using a while loop and something like
    String s;
    s = kb.next();
but I keep getting infinite loops and other errors with everything I try. Any ideas?

Comment: Where did you get an issue before in your code, can you show that?

Comment: compilation error at line 11 `Sal.add(kb.next());`. please check.

Comment: It's not so much an issue as that everytime I tried using a while loop it either didn't display anything or ran into an infinite loop. I'm pretty sure my problem lies in the fact that I don't I need a while loop instead of the sal.add but I just don't know what that would be. If you'd like, I can still post what I attempted though.

Answer (score 0):

For simple constant adding using a while loop, you need some type of termination condition:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < 5) {
    sal.add(kb.next());
    i++;
}

/* or */

String last = "";
while (!last.equals("end")) {
    last = kb.next();
    sal.add(last);
}
```

Comment: The second one will add `"end"` into `sal` as well.

Comment: True enough, but it's more about termination than the arraylist for the example :)

Comment: I tired this and it returned a blank line. It didn't get to the imput part

Comment: @Dukeling I can't remember off the top of my head, but it caused an issue with a class I taught earlier this summer. I suppose that's more of a personal thing, I removed it.

Comment: @user2920249 What did your code look like when it never got to the while loop?

Comment: @Rogue 
int count = 0;
          while (count<sal.size())
          {
          sal.add(kb.next());
          count++;
       }
          display(sal);
          displayb(sal);

Comment: @user2920249 You can't use `sal.size()` as `sal` starts off empty. You'll have to use a constant value (like `5`).

Comment: @Dukeling That causes an infinite loop when I replace sal.size() with anything

Comment: @user2920249 Are you sure it's an infinite loop and it's not just waiting for you to input more values? Keep in mind that values need to be separated by spaces and/or line breaks and you need to terminate it with a line break (press Enter at the end).

Comment: @Dukeling you were right haha. Sorry about that. Now I just need to figure out how to make it only return the number of words i put in (ie how when I use 5 i have to have 5 in total and can't only use three words). Also, thanks so much with the help, this had me stumped for like two hours.

Comment: @user2920249 How are you going to tell Java that you've reached the end? If they're all on one line, using `split` might be better - `List<String> sal = Arrays.asList(kb.nextLine().split(" "));`.

Comment: @Dukeling I'm really not sure. My teacher doesn't really tell you how to do the assignments until after they're due. So we need to read through the book and hope there's a way to do it mentioned in the book.

Although I'll try your method if that works best

Answer (score 0):

I am quite sure code is ok, you need to make following change though.

```
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);  
  ArrayList<String> sal = new ArrayList<String>();  
  sal.add(kb.next());
  sal.add(kb.next());
  **Sal.add(kb.next());**
```

here replace "Sal" with "sal"

Comment: woops. That was just a little error made by me. The code still does not work